# Good practice to pass values from child component to parent page in Blazor?

Tags: events, blazor, parent-child

Iam uncertain if I'am making a mistake using my approach to pass Objects from a Child Component to its consuming parent page in Blazor.
I have a poco class with ID,Name. A component with a select div from a list of poco-class obj..
User selectes a entrie and that entrie shall be shown on the parent page.
I am to unexperienct to see any problems with my solution. 1)Did I get it right? 2)If all is kind of okay what is with the OnInitializedAsync() there is no awaiting (Parent) shall I use OnInitialized() instead? 3)Is the use of Dispose correct? 4) Is this solution okay if I use the same approach maybe 20 times in one App for different components etc. Does this scale okay?
Thx nogood

ParentPage:

```cs
@page "/"
@inject MitarbeiterEventService MitarbeiterEventService

@implements IDisposable

<h1>ParentPage</h1>
<MitarbeiterSel></MitarbeiterSel>
<br />

@if (SelMitarbeiterFromChild != null)
{
    <p>Selected Obj. from Child: @SelMitarbeiterFromChild.Name </p>
}

@code{
    public MitarbeiterLite SelMitarbeiterFromChild;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        MitarbeiterEventService.EventMitarbeiterChangedInComp += HandelOnMitarbeiterChangedInComp;
    }

    public async void HandelOnMitarbeiterChangedInComp(object sender, MitarbeiterLite selMitarbeiter)
    {
        SelMitarbeiterFromChild = selMitarbeiter;

        await InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            StateHasChanged();

        });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        MitarbeiterEventService.EventMitarbeiterChangedInComp -= HandelOnMitarbeiterChangedInComp;
    }
}
```

The Code from the service (in the actual App I use MVVM so the event code would be in the ViewModel):

```cs
    public class MitarbeiterEventService
    {
        public event EventHandler<MitarbeiterLite> EventMitarbeiterChangedInComp;
        public void FireEvent(MitarbeiterLite selMitarbeiterFromComp)
        {
            EventMitarbeiterChangedInComp?.Invoke(this, selMitarbeiterFromComp);
        }
    }
```

And last the component it self:

```cs
@inject MitarbeiterEventService  MitarbeiterEventService

<h3>MitarbeiterSelection</h3>

<select class="form-control col-6" @onchange="@(x => OnMitarbeiterSelectedChanged(x.Value.ToString()))">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>--Mitarbeiter--</option>
    @foreach (var mita in MitarbeiterLitesLst)
    {
        <option value=@mita.Id>@mita.Name </option>
    }
</select>

@code {
    //Ini List 
    public List<MitarbeiterLite> MitarbeiterLitesLst = new List<MitarbeiterLite>
{
        new MitarbeiterLite("Henry"),
        new MitarbeiterLite("John"),
        new MitarbeiterLite("Sue"),
        new MitarbeiterLite("Mary"),
        new MitarbeiterLite("Jimmy")
    };

    public void OnMitarbeiterSelectedChanged(string guidAsString)
    {
        MitarbeiterEventService.FireEvent(MitarbeiterLitesLst.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.ToString() == guidAsString));
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your approach.  Service vs EventCallback - developers choice.   I always use a service that contains the data access code as well as the events associated with that data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To communicate with the parent use `EventCallback`. An Event Service is more useful when the consumer of the event is not a parent or a child, but some other component in your application that does not have a direct relationship with the component where you select the item.

In your scenario, I'd go for:

**Component**

```cs
    <h3> MitarbeiterSelection </h3>

<select class="form-control col-6"
        @onchange="@(x => OnMitarbeiterSelectedChanged(x.Value.ToString()))">

    <option value="" disabled selected hidden> --Mitarbeiter-- </option>

    @foreach (var mita in MitarbeiterLitesLst)
    {
        <option value=@mita.Id>@mita.Name </option>
    }

</select>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<MitarbeiterLite> OnItemSelected { get; set; }

    // Initialize List
    public List<MitarbeiterLite> MitarbeiterLitesLst = new List<MitarbeiterLite>
    {
        new MitarbeiterLite("Henry"),
        new MitarbeiterLite("John"),
        new MitarbeiterLite("Sue"),
        new MitarbeiterLite("Mary"),
        new MitarbeiterLite("Jimmy")
    };

    public void OnMitarbeiterSelectedChanged(string guidAsString)
    {
        MitarbeiterLite selected =
            MitarbeiterLitesLst
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.ToString() == guidAsString);

        OnItemSelected.InvokeAsync(selected);
    }
}
```

**Parent Page**

```cs
    @page "/"

    <h1> ParentPage </h1>
    <MitarbeiterSel OnItemSelected=@HandleOnMitarbeiterChangedInComp />
    <br />
    
    @if (SelMitarbeiterFromChild != null)
    {
        <p> Selected Obj. from Child: @SelMitarbeiterFromChild.Name  </p>
    }
    
    @code{
        public MitarbeiterLite SelMitarbeiterFromChild;
    
        public async Task HandelOnMitarbeiterChangedInComp(
            MitarbeiterLite selMitarbeiter)
        {
            SelMitarbeiterFromChild = selMitarbeiter;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thx it is working. Could you elaborate on the difference betwwen the two solutions. Pro/Con a little bit more if possible. I read from your post that I should use the Event solution if the Components/Pages are not Parents/Child. Like I need that input from a componetn in a class without GUI. And if I want to pass Infos from Child to Parents on the same Page I should use the Parameter EventCallBack Solution! Right? Do you have  info on the reasons? Thx again

Comment: Hmm I'am having touble to fully implement this solution. My problems start when I try to use it in my MVVM pattern. If I have the [Parameter] EventCallback and the OnSelChange Methode inside the direct code block of the Component it works. BUT I dont want code in the View. I inject the ViewModel in the View. If I have the [Parameter] etc. stuff in the ViewModel-Class then Blazor tells me on Build-> Error the Component doesnt have a Parameter with expacted name???

Comment: I know a lot of people have talked about MVVM in Blazor, but I really don't see the point of it.  Blazor achieves good enough separation of concerns in its OWN use of models in EditForm, and in the use of Dependency Injection.  I mean. . . you can use a separate class library for all your business logic if you want.