# How can I pass List from child component to parent component in blazor?

Tags: c#, frontend, components, blazor, backend

I started learning Blazor technology recently.

I just want to pass a simple array/arrayList to a parent component from a child component. Here is my code:

[Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y29QF.png)

[Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLTVv.png)

Visual Studio didn't find the error while compiling.

The problem is, when I send an array to a parent, it returns null. Please help me.

Comment: Maybe this will be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68177315/6895130

Comment: Use better name for event, like DataChanged, OnChange and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the below code:

```
<ChildComponent Data="TakeData" ...
```

your code removes EventCallback return value

Comment: Correct. Also this syntax `<ChildComponent Data="(newData) => TakeData(newData)" ...` would work, but is not necessary for this simple scenario.